# Force download is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, download, geddy

I want to prompt a download for a user when they click a link instead of open it in the browser.

with expressJS, it should be just like this :

```
app.get('/download', function (req, res) {
  res.download('public/uploads/sample.pdf');
});
```

how can I do it with GeddyJS ?

I tried this code, but it still open it in the browser, which is mean the "resp.setHeader" is not working.

```
this.download = function (req, resp, params) {
  var filename = 'sample.pdf';
  var file = 'public/uploads/sample.pdf';

  resp.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"');
  resp.sendFile(file);
};
```

Did I miss something?

Thanks a lot before.

Comment: Try setting Content-Type as well as Content-Disposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that Geddy's response object doesn't have a 'setHeader' method, so you need to reach in and set the header on the real Node response object.

```
resp.resp.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"');
```

Comment: still not working because the respond header is always: "
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Type:image/png
    Date:Fri, 05 Apr 2013 10:59:14 GMT
    Transfer-Encoding:chunked", no matter what string I placed with the resp.setHeader().
Is that possible that resp.sendFile() overrule the setHeader?
If yes, then how to set the header?

Comment: @fin Just to confirm, is your example with a different file? You said `image/png` but your question is about a PDF. I think I know why it didn't work, but I just want to confirm first.

Comment: ah sorry I mean "Connection:keep-alive Content-Type:application/pdf Date:Fri, 05 Apr 2013 10:59:14 GMT Transfer-Encoding:chunked". I was also trying to download an image, and still not working.

Comment: @fin Updated, let me know how that works. Geddy does some weird stuff with mixins, so the outer `resp` has a `setHeader` function, but I don't think it actually does anything.

Comment: nice.. working.. didn't know that `resp` also have `resp`.. thx man... at least it is fixed in this version.